# Ads Within Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im Trying To upgrade my app from adview in recyclerview

I am not able to add it within recyclerview similarly. Any views on how this is to be done in a Recyclerview?

private fun loadNext27(peoples: List) {

```
    try {
        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            minPeopleCount =
                peopleNearbyFirstRow.size + peopleNearbySecondRow.size + peopleNearbyThirdRow.size
            val maxPeopleCount = peoples.size.coerceAtMost(minPeopleCount!! + 27)

            minPeopleCountDummy = maxPeopleCount
            //   Log.d("PeopleNearByFragment", "loadNext27() maxPeopleCount--->$maxPeopleCount")

            peopleNearbyFirstRowList = ArrayList()
            peopleNearbySecondRowList = ArrayList()
            peopleNearbyThirdRowList = ArrayList()

            var i: Int = minPeopleCount as Int
            // Log.d("PeopleNearByFragment", "loadNext27() minPeopleCount--->$minPeopleCount")

            try {
                while (i < maxPeopleCount) {
```

i += 3

```
                    peopleNearbyFirstRowList += peoples[i]
                    peopleNearbySecondRowList += peoples[i.plus(1)]
                    peopleNearbyThirdRowList += peoples[i.plus(2)]

                    peopleNearbyFirstRow += peoples[i]
                    peopleNearbySecondRow += peoples[i.plus(1)]
                    peopleNearbyThirdRow += peoples[i.plus(2)]

                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            loadNext27UI(
                peopleNearbyFirstRowList,
                peopleNearbySecondRowList,
                peopleNearbyThirdRowList
          
            )
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

private fun reloadAllPeoples(){
peopleNearbyViewModel.allPeoples.observe(requireActivity()

```
    ) { peoples ->
        peoples.let {
            it.apply {

                allPeoples = it

                loadNext27(allPeoples!!)
                if (nestedScrollView != null) {

                    try {

                        nestedScrollView?.setOnScrollChangeListener { v: NestedScrollView, _: Int, scrollY: Int, _: Int, _: Int ->
                            if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).measuredHeight - v.measuredHeight) {

                                if (!isRecyclerViewWaitingToLoadData) {
                                    if (!loadedAllItems) {
                                        try {
                                            if (NetworkUtils.checkConnection()) {
                                                if (allPeoples!!.size > 27) {

                                                   mobileads()

                                                    loadNext27(allPeoples!!)
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                // progressbar1.visibility=View.VISIBLE
                                                val networkDialog = NetworkDialog()
                                                networkDialog.showDialog(requireActivity())
                                                networkDialog.setNetworkListener(this@PeopleNearByFragment)
                                            }
                                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                                            e.printStackTrace()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

private fun mobileads() {

```
        val adLoader: AdLoader = AdLoader.Builder(requireContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")

                    val styles = NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build()
                    val template = view?.findViewById<TemplateView>(R.id.my_template)
                    template?.setStyles(styles)
                    template?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    template?.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
                }
            })
            .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {


                    //template.visibility(View.GONE)
                }
            })
            .withNativeAdOptions(
                NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                .build())
            .build()
        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    }
```